# Australian English: developed or developped?

Tags: australian-english, doubled-consonants

According to https://proofreadmydocument.com.au/writing-tips/spelling-tips-the-doubling-up-rule/ and https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/resources/view/resource/20/, we should spell the past participle of "develop" as "developed", and the present particple as "developing" (mult-syllable, unstressed final syllable of the stem). Goolge prefers it, too. Still, it provides us with over 23800 references for

> site:.au "developped"

Are they all wrong?

As for Bing,

> site:.au "developed"

and

> site:.au "developped"

have approximately the same counts.

Comment: Google search results [do not give accurate estimates](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/398/191178). When I perform that search and go to the last page, it says there are only [121 results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqbwz.png).

Comment: They might not be all 'wrong' - some might be Aussies protesting the *lopping* of trees during land *development*.

Comment: Always refer to your national dictionary as an authoritarian source. Assuming that Macquarie *is* the commonly accepted source (I don't know for certain but suspect it is), then it will be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I do not know how normative it is considered in Australia, the Macquarie Dictionary refers to itself as "Australia's National Dictionary" on the cover. I have a slightly older printed version, but it is also available [online](https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/) for paying subscribers.

Macquarie Dictionary, Revised Third Edition (The Macquarie Library, 2003):
**developed** /də'vɛləpt/ *adjective* **1.** having undergone development. **2.** industrialised.
**developing** /də'vɛləpɪŋ/ *adjective* **1.** undergoing development  **2.** Also, **less-developed, underdeveloped** (of a country) in the early stages of developing an industrial economy.

Answer (score 1):

The OED recognises *developped* and *developping* as past tense/participle and present participle, but states that both have been "non-standard" since the eighteenth century.

The OED recognises a corpus of English around the world and were they in current Australian use, I am sure would say so.

Comment: nGram shows a surprising peak at the end of the 20th Century, mostly from scientific journals as far as I can tell. Nonetheless I'd consider the double-consonant spelling to be archaic, as the OED agrees.

Comment: @user49915 There is no mention of Australia.

Comment: @user49915 All I'm saying is that there is nothing in that OED entry which references the obsolete spelling to Australia.